# What conditions can cause intermittent JAXBExceptions?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm analysing some code where JAXB is the serialisation mechanism, and I'm at a loss to define what conditions a JAXB execption can reasonably represent:

1. Validation (not used in our code)
2. XML validity - should only be unmarshalling. We have unmarshalling tests for all our legacy JAXB serialisations that we have ever used
3. Annotation issues - presumably this is not a transient issue - if it works once, it'll always work
4. Property issues - again, if it's able to be set and got once, it should always be so.

So the only considerations I'm looking out for (as an exceptional case and not a development/coding error) are:

- Attempted unmarshalling of an unknown/unexpected type/document
- Serialised document modification/corruption

Are these the only 2 non development/deployment issues?
If serialisation works for an object structure, is there any way a JAXBException can occur hence? (Presuming a stablel/fully-loaded classloader etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are any coded listeners or mashalling hooks, then these parts of (your) customised code can cause exceptional conditions which will be wrapped in a `JAXBException`